# Refusing for turning on a zoom camera during an exam?

Tags: exams, cheating, education, online-learning, video-conference

Hello I have a question regarding video during exams.

My professor is hosting an exam using Zoom, and I was wondering if there was any basis for refusing to use the camera during the exam. Each student will be able to see each other unlike a [previous question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/147662/technologies-for-remote-proctoring-invigilating) asking about one-way monitoring.

The exam is also open-notes, and open-book. There is also an issue of cheating that is being discussed. The matter is being discussed because three exams already without the camera but the professor says its kind of just to make sure we are not doing anything sketchy. However, I feel its a contradiction because if the class "cheated" doing his past exams, then why give them the grade.

However, I am wondering if that means I can't refuse the camera.

Comment: I modified the tags, and I hope the question is on topic for the site.

Comment: What exactly is the reason for your objection to turning on the camera?

Comment: @DanRomik Kind of not in school to be watched, I have a disability I get up, and do things like go the bathroom, I listen to music because its helpful. I eat breakfast early in the morning, and I have to drink pills that require a wait time to I can eat typically I do this all during lecture, because the other exams have been during the weekend due before Monday. They were timed nonetheless. I hope this helps your comment.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky but if the exam was happening on campus (I assume you have experience with that) then you would be watched while taking it, wouldn’t you? So “not in school to be watched” is an illogical objection. Obviously you are in school to learn and get tested, being “watched” is only a necessary side effect you have to tolerate to allow the school to perform its essential functions. And if you tolerated it before Covid-19, I’d ask why the current situation is so different that you suddenly feel like rebelling against being watched while taking an exam when you previously accepted it.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky for what it’s worth, I think it’s reasonable to not like being watched when taking an exam, which is a stressful situation even when you’re not watched. And this is true for everyone, not just for someone with a disability. But students all around the world put up with it. I put up with it when I was a student, and everyone else I know did. I don’t see why you should feel you’re being reasonable to ask to be exempted from something every other student in the entire world has to accept.

Comment: As I alluded to in my answer before you mentioned any sort of disability, if you had disability accommodations in the past and this interferes with them, then maybe it's reasonable to object, but if there aren't technical constraints and you didn't have accommodations to take medications or eat during classes before then I'd agree with Dan.

Comment: @DanRomik I am at home now with my family, if I am taking an exam and its stressing out I go and talk to them, and kind of don't need to be accused of cheating when first of none of my parents are college graduates, my baby brother is in 5th grade, and my sister is an English major. I have my laptop in my bedroom I am not going to be lugging that around, and have people listen in to my business because that's not it. The thing is Co-VID changed lots now you have people to interact in your house I don't know if you do. My baby brother walks into the room needs help with something I help him.

Comment: @BryanKrause Your right I do have accommodations, I asked to update them but they said they still applied to online, I had to ask for extra time, and sometimes I didn't get and still outscored much of the class.

Comment: I am not new to a stackexchange I am going to post a new question in reference to testing.

Comment: Allowing you the same extra time that you got in person is reasonable and should be accommodated and if you aren't getting that despite your professor being aware then you should complain through your disability office. Having conversations with your family and being interrupted **during an exam** on the other hand is not reasonable, especially if you have a bedroom you can go into, unless there were some emergency situation like someone choking.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky I feel for you, and for every other student having to manage being in school through this very difficult period. It’s hard on everyone, and unfair that you and millions of others were put in this situation. But your objections to turning on your camera don’t sound reasonable, sorry. Anyway, it’s reasonable to discuss this with your professor, maybe they will be willing to work with you and figure out a solution of some sort. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to deal with this through your instructor or the university. Personally, I think that requiring you to use a camera has ethical and privacy concerns, but I don't get to judge. What should be the case and how you are constrained are probably quite different.

I wish you luck in such a pursuit, but have little faith that you will prevail. Such things are, of course, disruptive to those living in the same place as the student in many cases.

Complain if you can find a way to do so.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your professor plans to monitor video to prevent cheating. Since the exam is open note/open book, this would primarily be to make sure students are not collaborating between each other.

I think there are reasons this situation is unfortunate from the students' side: could students be penalized if their video freezes? (mine does all the time on Zoom calls despite a good internet connection and despite good incoming/outgoing audio throughout...) is it fair to give your class a view into your personal living situation?

It's also quite a difficult time from the professor's side: they're trying to make sure they can administer fair and honest exams while knowing that given sufficient leeway some fraction of students will use that to their advantage.

I think it's reasonable to ask your professor for flexibility, but you should *have your reasons/concerns in mind* and express those rather than only your solution (opting out of video). If you come at it as trying to work between your concerns and those of your instructor, you are more likely to be able to come to some intermediate arrangement.

However, depending on the time until the exam, size of the class, etc, they may not be able to make any allowances in the sake of fairness unless there is a real serious concern. Having your classmates able to see you is probably not going to be sufficient, since they would normally see you in-person as well, unless you already have some disability considerations related to that. They'll all be focused on their own exams anyways and probably won't even have you on-screen.

OP's logic suggesting that *because past exams didn't have video this exam doesn't need video* (paraphrased) doesn't make much sense to me. Maybe this is a particularly important exam (a final?), or maybe the professor has some circumstantial evidence that cheating happened previously that is insufficient to act on, like certain students having very similar answers. There might not be much they can do about the exams they've already given, but they are probably hoping for a better result for the next one.

Comment: Same thing my classmates are saying. But thanks +1.

Comment: You say "The logic about past exams doesn't make much sense to me." then go on to give a very reasonable justification. What you are saying in the last paragraph seems like a good justification to require students to turn on the cameras.

Comment: @Eracnet I meant OP's logic ("However, I feel its a contradiction because if the class "cheated" doing his past exams, then why give them the grade." - this was also expressed similarly and maybe more clearly in a comment that has since been removed), not their professor's. I'll clarify. Indeed the professor's logic makes sense.